# Get List of Files sorted by name from directory

Tags: c#, file, sorting, directory

I need to get list of files sorted by name from directory.

My files are named as:

```
TestFile_1.xml,
TestFile_2.xml
TestFile_3.xml
.
.
TestFile_10.xml
TestFile_11.xml
```

I am using below snippet for sorting

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(jsonFileInfo.FolderPath);
FileSystemInfo[] files = di.GetFileSystemInfos();
var orderedFiles = files.OrderBy(f => f.Name);`
```

with this snnipet, I am getting result as

```
TestFile_1.xml,
TestFile_10.xml
TestFile_11.xml
.
.
TestFile_2.xml
TestFile_3.xml
.
.
```

How do I sort it?

Comment: That works already. Otherwise you should clarify the requirement. A name is a string and a string does not know that `10` is "larger" than "2".

Comment: Simple solution: name the files `TestFile_01` instead of `TestFile_1`

Comment: I can not rename file from `TestFile_1` to `TestFile_01`. The file name will always remain as `TestFile1`

Comment: Do the files all begin with `TestFile_`?

Comment: And all your files follow the pattern TestFile_[number].xml ?

Comment: No, not all files follow the pattern TestFile_[number].xml but all files begin with `TestFile_`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A name is a string and a  `"10"` is not  *larger* than "2". If you want to sort by the number after the underscore:

```
var orderedFiles = files
    .Select(f => new{ 
        File = f, 
        NumberPart = f.Name.Substring(f.Name.IndexOf("_") + 1)
    })
    .Where(x => x.NumberPart.All(Char.IsDigit))
    .Select(x => new { x.File, Number = int.Parse(x.NumberPart) })
    .OrderBy(x => x.Number)
    .Select(x => x.File);
```

If you want to include all files which don't end with the number anyway, those should come first:

```
orderedFiles = files
    .Select(f => new
    {
        File = f,
        NumberPart = f.Name.Substring(f.Name.IndexOf("_") + 1)
    })
    .Select(x => new { x.File, x.NumberPart, AllDigit = x.NumberPart.All(Char.IsDigit) })
    .Select(x => new
    {
        x.File,
        Number = x.AllDigit ? int.Parse(x.NumberPart) : (int?)null
    })
    .OrderBy(x => x.Number.HasValue)
    .ThenBy(x => x.Number ?? 0)
    .Select(x => x.File);
```

If you even want that a static file-name is always on the top (as commented), you could use:

```
....
.OrderByDescending(x => x.File.Name.Equals("TestFile_cover.xml", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
.ThenBy(x => x.Number.HasValue)
.ThenBy(x => x.Number ?? 0)
.Select(x => x.File);
```

Comment: This approach is fine if my all files follow the pattern TestFile_[number].xml but not all files follow the pattern TestFile_[number].xml, First file of the list Should always be `TestFile_cover.xml`